# For loop overwrites previous object?

Tags: c++

I am just starting learning C++, and made it into chapter 17 of learncpp.com. I am trying to build a little game while learning.

edit: I changed the main question, see my comment.

I made a Player class, and want the user to input the amount of players and give them a unique name.

The Player class has members like m_name, m_points, m_stuff_they_own.

I spend a long time on this already... trying to use unique names to initialize a Player, and second, let the user input a Name which is stored in member m_name.

I think I get it now, but just want to confirm and really get my head around it. I used player0 as a name for a Player, and then store that Player in the playerArray. And then player0 gets destroyed at the following '}', the end of the loop?

So the name player0 is never stored or used anywhere beyond that point?
There is just a Player in the array which doesn't really have an name/identifier? I can only 'call' the Player with playerArray[0].get/set/whtvr/Something()?

Edit: I understand the player0 variable now. My (new) main/second question is why the object m_name seem to overwrite each other.

Thanks in advance.

My class:

```
class Player {
public:
    // some getters/setters

Player::Player(std::string_view name) // constructor
    : m_name{ name }
{}

private:
    std::string_view m_name{ "default" };
    // more members
```

Code to enter player:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<Player> playerArray;
    playerArray.reserve(6);

    std::cout << "How many players do you want? (2-6)\n";
    const int playerCount{ getInteger() }; // todo: input check

    std::string temp{};
    for (int i = 0; i < playerCount; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter name for player " << i << '\n';
        std::cin >> temp;
        std::cout << temp << '\n';
        Player player0{ temp };
        playerArray.emplace_back( player0 );
    }

    std::cout << playerArray[0].getName() << '\n';
    std::cout << playerArray[1].getName() << '\n';
```

Comment: Variable names aren't stored in the executable program. Once the compiler is finished, variable names no longer exists. Variables are just for making programming so much easier. And yes, once the loop ends, there's no variable named `player0` any more, it's scope is inside the loop body only.

Comment: By the way, the variable `player0` isn't needed, you can do `playerArray.emplace_back(temp);` And I suggest you define the variable `temp` inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks, when I use playerArray.emplace_back(temp); the first character is missing, some std::cin quirk I suppose.

Comment: Remember that `std::cin >> temp;`  will read up to the first space character that you type so if you type "Jon Doe" expect `temp` will have "Jon" the first iteration and the "Doe" will be left for future input.

Comment: "And yes, once the loop ends, there's no variable named player0 any more, it's scope is inside the loop body only." Right, if there is a new variable made each iteration, and the temp is being filled by user the each iteration, how do I end up with playerArray[0] and playerArray[1] having the same m_name? What am I missing?

Comment: What type is `Player::m_name` -- `std::string` or `std::string_view`?  You really need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Player::m_name is a std::string_view and private. I got the same result with std::string. I'll try to provide an example later.

Comment: The that's almost certainly the problem.  `m_name` refers to the data in the locally scoped `temp` variable and will end up referring to invalid memory (probably via dangling pointer(s)).  Hence undefined behaviour.

Comment: You are seeing this because all the string views are refering to the same string. I refrained from writing an answer because I am sure it's a duplicate. However I don't understand what your comment "get the same result with std::string" means. If you use a `std::string` member instead, it should work properly. Can you show what the exact code is?

Comment: I've quickly updated the code to provide a better example. The program isn't that big, or actually, this part is the start of the program. I guess what you say makes sort of sense for me as a beginner, but I do not use pointers (at least not explicit). I did test it, but not enought. I changed the member to std::string (leaving the constructor) and it works now! Thanks a lot, at learncpp they initialized the m_name string_view with a c-style array string, which lives forever. I guess that makes all the difference here?

Comment: A string literal is valid throughout the lifetime of the program.

Comment: G.M. was right:

>  m_name refers to the data in the locally scoped temp variable and
> will end up referring to invalid memory (probably via dangling
> pointer(s)). Hence undefined behaviour.

I was looking at the old/dangling temp variable data I guess. I spend so much time on this... ah well won't be the last time I gues... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I originally thought this is one of those "`std::string_view` points to something that immediately goes out of scope" questions. However this one turns out to be more nuanced and I hope my explanation helps clear up things.

First you need to understand what a `std::string_view` is. All it keeps track is a pointer to const char and a length. It does not store any of the actual string contents in it. That is by design. A `string_view` is very cheap to copy around, unlike a `string`. However, if for any reason the underlying buffer is invalidated, you run into undefined behavior.

In your code,

```
    std::string temp{};
    for (int i = 0; i < playerCount; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter name for player " << i << '\n';
        std::cin >> temp;
        std::cout << temp << '\n';
        Player player0{ temp };
        playerArray.emplace_back( player0 );
    }
    std::cout << playerArray[0].getName() << '\n';
    std::cout << playerArray[1].getName() << '\n';
```

The nuance is that the `string` to which the `string_view` refers (`temp` here) is not out of scope when the `string_view` is used, so you are not immediately in the danger of UB.

In each iteration, a `std::string_view` is indirectly constructed from the string `temp`. That `string_view` contains two information: `temp.data()` and `temp.size()`. These two data are then copied into the vector. Note that the underlying buffer is never copied. In the next iteration, `temp` is assigned a new value, and both `temp.data()` and `temp.size()` may change. What happens here really depends on whether/how they changes. Let me give some example.

Let's assume that in the last iteration the `temp=="abc"`, in the new iteration:

- If `temp.data()` changes due to reallocation, all bets are off and you are in the UB realm due to accessing objects out of their lifetime.
- Otherwise, if the new `temp.size()<3`, you can get some munged result due to that the underlying char array has been overwritten. If now `temp=="x"`, you may get `{'x','\0','c'}` in your `string_view`.
- Otherwise, if the new `temp.size()>=3` but no reallocation occurs,
  You are safe from UB, but the `string_view` no longer contains what you expect if you print it. It would seem as if you have overwritten it. In the case where `temp.size()>3`, you will observe a `string_view` as if it contains the first 3 letters of the new string.

Due to Small String Optimization(SSO), it is actually not that common to have your `temp.data()` invalidated unless you have really long input strings.

In other words, If all your input strings are shorter than or equally long as all input strings in previous iterations (so the buffer never reallocates), or if you first `reserve()` a large enough buffer before any user input, you are free from UB, but the `string_view` will not contain what you expect anyway and will appear to be munged or overwritten. Otherwise, since the standard allows reallocation, your code suffers from UB. The solution is of course use `std::string` instead, which actually copies the underlying bytes. If you choose to do so, you should avoid the copy of your object, and write

```
playerArray.emplace_back(std::move(temp));
```

instead. Even when the type is cheap to copy you should still use `emplace_back` instead of declaring an object solely to push it to a vector later. This is one thing you misunderstood about the comments. The comment is not telling you to replace `push_back(player0)` with `emplace_back(player0)`.

For `string_view`s constructed from raw string literals, you need to understand that string literals are of type `const char[N]` where `N` is the total number of the characters in the string literal (including the terminal NUL). The lifetime of a string literal is the whole program run, so you are safe when using `string_view`s constructed from them.

Comment: Thanks for your constructive comment.

I used a C-style string before trying to get the user to input the names. I even copied the comment from learncpp.com in my code: "We use std::string_view here because the name is a C-style string literal and does not need to be modified". I mostly used same-sized-but-different-letters-strings to test, so I never saw any garbage as you explained, which *might* have pointed (pun intended) me to the string_view problem....

Your last comment about not making a object, why does:

playerArray[i] = Player(temp);

Comment: (correction)

About your last comment using playerArray.emplace_back(tmp); without Player, why does:
playerArray[i] = temp; not work, but = Player(temp); does?

(I did change the logic a bit, so that's why I am using this method now).

Comment: `emplace_back` means constructing your object in-place using the appropriate constructor. It calls the constructor on your behalf so you don't need to construct the object by yourself at all. `=temp` should work if all you did is replacing `string_view` with `string`. Can you give more details? Of course you cannot use `playerArray[i] = temp` to extend the vector, but the assignment is otherwise fine.